# Can I style a Wordpress/Advanced Custom Fields/Radio Button for display within the 'Edit Page' option?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Radio Button field that I created using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for WP.  Right now it can display either horizontally or vertically.  Is it possible to style this within the 'Edit Page'  screen so that each button is displayed near a group of repeater fields?

I would like to learn more generally, if/how I can style a 'Edit Page' for users within my company to use when creating a viewable page for end users.  Non interested in how to style the rendered page that is the result of this process.  Hope this is clear.

Comment: I don't think you can do very much to control the actual layout of ACF generated metaboxes, but you can add your own custom fields and admin edit page metaboxes yourself that look however you want, it's just more work.  You can also add admin specific stylesheets.  But ACF is designed to make it easy to NOT have to do all this, at the expense of total customization.  Unless you are pretty comfortable with HTML, CSS, and basic JS/PHP you will probably be out of your depth doing this.

Comment: Is there any flexibility, even as simple as changing the tab from 'Add Row' to something else?